# Problems stretching background to fit screen on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Supersized (http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) to stretch a background image to fit the screen.

It works great in desktop browsers and in iPhone in portrait mode, but in iPhone landscape, the text overflows the screen, and also the image, which does not stretch to the bottow below the initial "view".

Any suggestions?

I'v tried CSS3 background-size with the same results.

Demo:
http://www.retype.se/temp/holding/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
```

You can play around with the attributes a bit to get your desired behavior. More information on this tag can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Thanks, but i have been playing around with viewport settings without successfully solve the problem :/

Comment: The viewport will need to be set for mobile if you are trying to fill the whole screen with something and prevent overflow. You will need the meta tag to fix this issue.

Comment: Actually, some more fiddling made it look decent now. Thanks :)